# Sort a Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to sort the following Linq query by the using a field from the table called priority.

```
foreach (var faculty in specialty.faculty_specialties.Where(f => f.faculty.active))
```

I tried adding: `.OrderByDescending(p => p.priority)` to the end with no success.
I'm using C# & Visual Studio in an MVC project. Thanks

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/
http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion
http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Now I am confused on what you try to achieve (this is why you get many downvotes). Lets not get disturbed by that. Please explain in your question better what you try to do. It seems you want to loop through faculty objects but there is no looping in the foreach.

Comment: Define "no success". What *did* happen, and why is it not what you want to happen?

Comment: OrderByDescending should definitely work. Please add some details on the expected and actual results.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments and helping me to better clarify my question. I'm looping through faculty members (that are active) and am trying to use a field called 'priority' to order the results. Right now it displays the faculty members and sorts by the id. Looks like I wrote it wrong...
foreach (var faculty in specialty.faculty_specialties.Where(f => f.faculty.active).OrderByDescending(p => p.faculty.priority))

Comment: So what happens when you put in `OrderByDescending` correctly?

Comment: @NetMage > it works now. Forgot to add that to the end of my comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by breaking up your logic into separate operations rather than trying to write everything in one line. Compilers are smart cookies so they optimize things quite well, there's no point making your code harder to read/understand:

```
var facultySpecialties = specialty.faculty_specialties
  .Where(fs => fs.faculty.active)
  .ToList(); // Executes the query to retrieve faculty specialties.

foreach(var facultySpecialty in facultySpecialties)
{
  // do stuff.
}
```

Keep mindful of the scope of the entities you are referring to with your queries. The above query will be returning faculty_specialties, not faculties. A gotcha to beware of: since this returns fac_specs, if you want to access details from the fac_spec and the faculty in the foreach loop then .Include the faculty as well.

```
var facultySpecialties = specialty.faculty_specialties
  .Include(fs => fs.faculty)
  .Where(fs => fs.faculty.active)
  .ToList();
```

If you just want Faculties, and don't need info from the fac_spec:

```
var faculties = specialty.faculty_specialties
  .Select(fs => fs.faculty)
  .Where(f => f.active)
  .ToList();
```

This selects the faculty from our fac_specs. Note the Where clause changes because the scope after the `.Select()` becomes Faculties instead of Faculty_Specialities. If you still want details from the fac_specs, you can use a `.Include(f => f.faculty_specialties)` however don't include relationships if they aren't needed as it increases the performance cost and transfer cost (size) of the queries.

Now you want the faculties ordered. The question is what entity does priority apply? If Priority is a field in Faculty then:

```
var faculties = specialty.faculty_specialties
  .Select(fs => fs.faculty)
  .Where(f => f.active)
  .OrderBy(f => f.Priority)
  .ToList();
```

However, I suspect the priority is on the faculty_speciality.

If you have navigation properties from faculty back to faculty_specialities (I'm assuming a many-to-many relationship so faculty could have a `ICollection<faculty_specialities>` mapped) and faculties are a DbSet in your context, you might want to restructure the query since this will make ordering a bit easier:

```
var faculties = dbContext.Faculties
  .Where(f => f.active && f.faculty_specialties.Any(fs => fs.specialty.specialtyId == specialty.specialtyId))
  .ToList();
```

To implement an order by on the faculty_speciality.priority:

```
var faculties = dbContext.Faculties
  .Where(f => f.active 
    && f.faculty_specialties.Any(fs => fs.specialty.specialtyId == specialty.specialtyId))
  .OrderByDescending(f => f.faculty_specialties.Min(fs => fs.priority))
  .ToList();
```

You can try an order-by on the original query with something like:

```
var faculties = specialty.faculty_specialties
  .OrderBy(fs => fs.priority)
  .Select(fs => fs.faculty)
  .Where(f => f.active)
  .ToList();
```

However I'm not sure this sorting would honored down to the final result set.

One last thing to consider with queries like this is that as systems grow the amount of data may make operations like this very expensive as the # of facilities for a given specialty increase. You should consider imposing a limit to the result size and paging support early on using `.Take()` and `.Skip()` unless the system's size will be capped at a reasonable number.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and for helping me think about how to reason the solution. I got it working now.

Comment: Why do you prefer using `ToList` rather than having `foreach` create the objects without the overhead of creating a `List`?

Comment: From a memory perspective there is no difference. Without the `.ToList()` you will have an `IQueryable<T>` which will be executed and loaded on first access. (first iteration) Calling `.ToList()` merely marks that point of execution. Any Linq operations *after* the point of execution will be Linq2Object rather than Linq2EF. So for instance if you want to call a private method, extension method, or unmapped property via further Linq reductions these can be done safely after the `ToList()`. This also gives you a debugging point where you can inspect the results.